# angular 2 - jquery is not defined in .Net angular 2

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular

I'm reading this article: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

==> I'm trying to build an .NET angular web app (MVC)

Everything works fine until I try to use jQuery to catch a button with `id="myButton"`

I get the following error:

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: ReferenceError: $ is
>   not defined

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: if you use angular, you don't need jquery. In Angular you add an ng-click to a button and in that method you have there you define what happens. If it's Angular 2 then there will be an Angular2 specific way of doing things.

Comment: I use popover in bootstrap 3 (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) . I have to add block code below and angular2 says $ is not defined: $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})

Answer (score 0):

If you use webpack for build you can use this plugin:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
  })
]
```

As you are using server side rendering, the problem is that jQuery is not defined in Node.

Comment: I think more about this context: I want to use bootstrap 3 popover, 
I have to add these code and $ is still not defined, same error as I meet above
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
})